# Wrapper around slice is doing weird things

Tags: go

I am probably wasting my time implementing this, but I am looking for a way to push/pop to a slice more easily, so I have this:

```
package h

import (
    "sync"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type List struct {
   internalList []interface{}
    mux sync.Mutex
}


func MakeList(l []interface{}) List{
    return List{l, sync.Mutex{}}
}


func (l List) Add(args ...interface{}) List{
    l.mux.Lock()
    l.internalList = append(l.internalList, args...)
    log.Info(l.internalList)
    l.mux.Unlock()
    return l;
}

func (l List) Push(v interface{}) List {
    l.mux.Lock()
    l.internalList = append(l.internalList, v)
    log.Info("internal:",l.internalList);
    l.mux.Unlock()
    return l;
}


func (l List) Pop() interface{}{
    l.mux.Lock()
    length :=len(l.internalList);
    log.Info("the length is:", length)
    if length < 1 {
        return nil;
    }
    last := l.internalList[length-1]
    l.internalList = l.internalList[:length-1]
    l.mux.Unlock()
    return last;
}

func (l List) GetLength() int {
    return len(l.internalList);
}

func (l List) Shift() interface{} {
    l.mux.Lock()
    if len(l.internalList) < 1 {
        return nil;
    }
    first := l.internalList[0];
    l.internalList = l.internalList[1:]
    l.mux.Unlock()
    return first;
}

func (l List) Unshift(v interface{}){
    l.mux.Lock()
    l.internalList = append([]interface{}{v}, l.internalList...)
    l.mux.Unlock()
}

func (l List) GetValue() []interface{}{
    return l.internalList
}
```

and then I use it like so:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "huru/h"
    "huru/utils"
)

func main(){

    x := h.List{}
    x.Push(3)
    logrus.Info("value:",x.GetValue())
    logrus.Info("len:",x.GetLength());
    logrus.Info(x.Pop());


}
```

but the weird thing is I get this:

```
INFO[0000] internal:[3]                                 
INFO[0000] value:[]                                     
INFO[0000] len:0                                        
INFO[0000] the length is:0                              
INFO[0000] <nil>
```

I have no idea why 3 gets added to the slice, but then the slice length mysteriously goes to zero and when I pop() I get nil. Anybody know why that's happening?

Given the existing answer, I am wondering if there is a difference between:

```
func (l *List) Add(args ...interface{}) *List {
    l.mux.Lock()
    l.internalList = append(l.internalList, args...)
    log.Info(l.internalList)
    l.mux.Unlock()
    return l;
}

func (l *List) Push(v interface{}) *List {
    l.mux.Lock()
    l.internalList = append(l.internalList, v)
    log.Info("internal:",l.internalList)
    l.mux.Unlock()
    return l
}
```

and

```
func (l *List) Add(args ...interface{}) List {
    l.mux.Lock()
    l.internalList = append(l.internalList, args...)
    log.Info(l.internalList)
    l.mux.Unlock()
    return *l;
}

func (l *List) Push(v interface{}) List {
    l.mux.Lock()
    l.internalList = append(l.internalList, v)
    log.Info("internal:",l.internalList)
    l.mux.Unlock()
    return *l
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes there is difference, the second won't let you chain your calls. https://play.golang.com/p/lOws9oBdD4G

Comment: You **must** **not** copy a sync.Mutex. Your code is so wrong it would not even pass basic vetting. Always read the documentation of things you use and take the Tour of Go once more if you are unsure about such basics.

Comment: @Volker unfortunately I am one of those people that learns by doing not by reading docs. Reading docs is "in one ear out the other" :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your methods are mutating the data, they need to use pointer receivers:

```
func (l *List) Push(v interface{}) List {
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, the state will be updated on the *copy* of the struct, and lost after that.

More on that in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values)

Update: I noticed that you return the updated value from your methods. If the copy is what you actually want, you need to keep the value receivers as they are now, but then use the returned values in your calling code as well:

```
x = x.Push(3)
```

Comment: ah, I see, so the struct will get copied if a pointer is not used?

Comment: also, what I should I return from the "method", a pointer? like `return *l`?

Comment: @MrCholo I updated the answer. If you want to update the struct _in place_, just use the pointer receiver, and then you don't need to return anything. But if you want a copy, you also need to use the returned value on the caller side.

Comment: Oh I am returning `l` just as a convenience API, for chaining calls.